# xmlHttpRequest.send crashes Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using a Chrome Extension to send a REST command to a simple API.

I have an icon that has a popup menu:

```
<body>
   <button id="Enable">Enable</button>
   <button id="Disable">Disable</button>
   <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is the code in popup.js

```
  Enable.onclick = function(element) 
  {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://192.168.100.110/admin/api.php?enable&auth=xxxx", false);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    request.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
  };
```

The URL works fine when sent from the browser.

When I open the Debugger using "Inspect PopUp" and click the Enable button in the popup menu the code crashes the extension at request.send();

The debugger also closes.  I don't see any error messages.

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Enable/Disable",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Enables/Disables",

  "options_page": "options.html",
  "browser_action": 
  {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": 
    {
      "16": "images/Icon - 16x16.png"
    }
  }
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Any suggestions as to where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome with synchronous XHR. Try making an async request.

Comment: Making it Async worked.  If you write it as an answer I'll mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time chrome extensions crash because they run out of memory. Due to high memory usage chrome runs out of memory, therefore it stops the process(extension) as every process is an independent thread.

You can check the memory usage of your extension(or any of your chrome tabs) by
opening the Chrome task manager (Shift+Esc).